# Dynamic spot of TextView within ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Is it possible somehow to define spot of TextView dynamically along the horizontal line in `ConstraintLayout`?
I have the horizontal line and I have some integer value (it can be from 0 to 40) and if it will be lower it should be located closer to the left end of this horizontal line, and if the value will be higher, the textview should be located closer to the right end of this horizontal line.

[image]

Now my xml layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

    ...

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lowestScoreTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_3xl"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_xl"
        android:text="0"
            ...
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/firstLine"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/titleTextView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/firstLine"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_2xs"
        ...
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_2xs"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_xs"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/lowestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/secondLine"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lowestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/lowestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_2xs"
            ...
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_xs"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/firstLine"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/thirdLine"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lowestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/lowestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/thirdLine"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_2xs"
            ...
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_2xs"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/secondLine"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/highestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lowestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/lowestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/highestScoreTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_xl"
            android:text="40"
            ...
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/thirdLine"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/lowestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/lowestScoreTextView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" />

    ...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `TextView` a Horizontal [`Bias`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#Bias) programatically by using [`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet):

```
ConstraintSet setWithBias = new ConstraintSet();
setWithBias.clone(constraintLayout); // You'd require a reference to this ConstraintLayout through findViewById()
setWithBias.setHorizontalBias(R.id.OfYourTextView, 0.2); // 20% horizontal bias (0 - extreme left, 1 - extreme right)
setWithBias.applyTo(constraintLayout); // Apply changes to your ConstraintLayout
```

Note that your `TextView`'s left and right edge must be connected to the appropriate extremes for this to work. **According to your code: `firstLine`'s left edge and `thirdLine`'s right edge.**

If you don't set the bias, it'd stay in the middle with the above constraints, which implicitly indicates `bias` being 0.5